# Can you identify this LEGO board game with square paper tokens?

Tags: part-identification, lego-games

I have some of these cards which I found at the bottom of an old box of mixed LEGO and I am trying to identify them.
I think they came from a game maybe?

I used to get the Bricks n Pieces magazine, but not sure if they are from that. I would guess they are from the 1990's.
Each card is approx 1cm square...

I vaguely remember playing with them, but can't identify what they are from - nor can Lego themselves. These four are all I have left.

Can anyone help?

[image: Lego game identification]

Comment: The 2 sets pictured are [6811-1: Pulsar Charger](https://brickset.com/sets/6811-1/Pulsar-Charger) from 1990 and [6988-1: Alpha Centauri Outpost](https://brickset.com/sets/6988-1/Alpha-Centauri-Outpost) from 1991. That may offer a clue to how old it is.

Comment: thanks for identifying the sets and years. It might help narrow it down a bit... I'm still none the wiser yet though...

Answer (score 6):

found it at last...!

They are cards from this game from the 1990s

Space Police / Blacktron II / M:Tron Poster Game

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=921800

Comment: Nice work! I'm glad that you figured it out!